# How to make the second line of the wrapped text appear appear right under the first one, like in the picture:

Tags: css, alignment, word-wrap

is there a way to make the second line of text, appear as if it had margin-left (or something) so that is directly underneath where the first one starts?

I know I could achieve a similar result using a `<table>`, but I'd really like not to, so is there another way?

[image: Text Wrapped Around an Svg]

```css
.thumbs {width:30%;
position:relative;
top:45px;
transform:rotate(180deg);}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<symbol id="thumbs" viewbox="0 0 400 150"><path d="M141.05 67.45c0 3.601 1.649 7.05 4.2 9.3-1.801 2.4-2.551 5.4-2.25 8.4.6 6.3 6.3 11.4 12.899 11.4h19.5l-1.2 9.3c-.3 2.85-.3 5.25.301 7.649 2.25 9.75 10.949 16.65 21 16.65 2.25 0 4.5-.9 6.15-2.55 1.65-1.65 2.55-3.75 2.55-6v-12.3c0-5.4 1.5-10.5 4.351-15.15l5.25-8.4c.75-1.199 1.8-2.1 3-2.699 1.05 3.3 4.05 5.699 7.649 5.699h17.25c4.5 0 8.101-3.6 8.101-8.1v-50.55c0-4.5-3.601-8.101-8.101-8.101h-17.55c-4.5 0-8.1 3.601-8.1 8.101v1.2c-3.9-3.45-9-5.551-14.55-5.551h-38.101c-3.45 0-6.899 1.5-9.3 3.9s-3.6 5.55-3.45 8.85c0 1.2.15 2.25.601 3.45a12.478 12.478 0 0 0-6.75 11.101c0 1.649.3 3.3.899 4.8-2.7 2.551-4.349 6.002-4.349 9.601zm82.649-37.2c0-.3.301-.6.601-.6h17.399c.301 0 .601.3.601.6v50.551c0 .3-.3.6-.601.6h-17.55c-.3 0-.6-.3-.6-.6V30.25h.15zm-72.3 32.7c1.2-.6 2.101-1.649 2.4-3 .3-1.35 0-2.7-.9-3.75-.75-.899-1.05-1.95-1.05-3 0-2.399 1.8-4.5 4.2-4.95 1.5-.3 2.85-1.199 3.45-2.699.6-1.5.449-3-.45-4.351-.601-.75-.9-1.8-.9-2.85 0-1.2.45-2.55 1.351-3.45 1.05-1.05 2.55-1.65 4.05-1.65h38.1c7.95 0 14.55 6.45 14.55 14.551v27.6c-3.75.9-6.899 3.15-9 6.45l-5.25 8.399c-3.6 5.7-5.55 12.301-5.55 19.051v12.3c0 .3-.149.6-.3.75-.15.149-.45.3-.75.3-6.6 0-12.15-4.5-13.65-10.8-.3-1.351-.449-3-.149-4.95l1.35-10.5c.3-1.8-.3-3.6-1.5-5.1-1.2-1.351-3-2.25-4.8-2.25h-20.7c-2.55 0-5.1-2.101-5.399-4.5-.15-1.801.75-3.601 2.25-4.65 1.35-.9 2.1-2.55 1.949-4.2-.149-1.649-1.199-3-2.85-3.6-1.95-.75-3.15-2.55-3.15-4.65-.151-1.951.899-3.6 2.698-4.501z"/></symbol></svg>

<div class="text-with-borders" style="margin: 0 auto;display:block;;text-align: left;
max-width:600px;">
<p><svg class="thumbs" role="img"><use xlink:href="#thumbs" /></svg>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
</div>
```

Comment: Using what HTML?

Comment: @David <div class="test"><p><svg><use ...></svg>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</div> .

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex` css property as shown below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div style="display:flex;">
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
<span  style="margin-left: 10px;">This is some text. This is some text.This is some text.This is some text.This is some text.This is some text.This is some text.This is some text.This is some text.This is some text.This is some text.This is some text.This is some text.This is some text.This is some text.This is some text.This is some text.</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Use your html like this** 
Keep the svg out of the div

```
<div class="test" style="display: flex;">
   <svg>
      <use ...>
   </svg>
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, @Nandita Arora Sharma!. I have the following html - <div class="test"><p><svg><use ...></svg>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</div>. So, when I tried used display:flex; it aligned the text just like I wanted vertically, but It also became unaligned horizontally. I tried adding margin-top and increasing the line-height, but that didn't help. Also, some of the Icons now are smaller for whatever reason.

Comment: Can you show me some image of the issue ? See if my updated answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with the ***Flexbox*** is indeed a good decision:

```css
.thumbs {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  /*top: 45px;*/
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.text-with-borders {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  align-items: center; /* centers them vertically */
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  /*text-align: left;*/
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="thumbs" viewbox="0 0 400 150"><path d="M141.05 67.45c0 3.601 1.649 7.05 4.2 9.3-1.801 2.4-2.551 5.4-2.25 8.4.6 6.3 6.3 11.4 12.899 11.4h19.5l-1.2 9.3c-.3 2.85-.3 5.25.301 7.649 2.25 9.75 10.949 16.65 21 16.65 2.25 0 4.5-.9 6.15-2.55 1.65-1.65 2.55-3.75 2.55-6v-12.3c0-5.4 1.5-10.5 4.351-15.15l5.25-8.4c.75-1.199 1.8-2.1 3-2.699 1.05 3.3 4.05 5.699 7.649 5.699h17.25c4.5 0 8.101-3.6 8.101-8.1v-50.55c0-4.5-3.601-8.101-8.101-8.101h-17.55c-4.5 0-8.1 3.601-8.1 8.101v1.2c-3.9-3.45-9-5.551-14.55-5.551h-38.101c-3.45 0-6.899 1.5-9.3 3.9s-3.6 5.55-3.45 8.85c0 1.2.15 2.25.601 3.45a12.478 12.478 0 0 0-6.75 11.101c0 1.649.3 3.3.899 4.8-2.7 2.551-4.349 6.002-4.349 9.601zm82.649-37.2c0-.3.301-.6.601-.6h17.399c.301 0 .601.3.601.6v50.551c0 .3-.3.6-.601.6h-17.55c-.3 0-.6-.3-.6-.6V30.25h.15zm-72.3 32.7c1.2-.6 2.101-1.649 2.4-3 .3-1.35 0-2.7-.9-3.75-.75-.899-1.05-1.95-1.05-3 0-2.399 1.8-4.5 4.2-4.95 1.5-.3 2.85-1.199 3.45-2.699.6-1.5.449-3-.45-4.351-.601-.75-.9-1.8-.9-2.85 0-1.2.45-2.55 1.351-3.45 1.05-1.05 2.55-1.65 4.05-1.65h38.1c7.95 0 14.55 6.45 14.55 14.551v27.6c-3.75.9-6.899 3.15-9 6.45l-5.25 8.399c-3.6 5.7-5.55 12.301-5.55 19.051v12.3c0 .3-.149.6-.3.75-.15.149-.45.3-.75.3-6.6 0-12.15-4.5-13.65-10.8-.3-1.351-.449-3-.149-4.95l1.35-10.5c.3-1.8-.3-3.6-1.5-5.1-1.2-1.351-3-2.25-4.8-2.25h-20.7c-2.55 0-5.1-2.101-5.399-4.5-.15-1.801.75-3.601 2.25-4.65 1.35-.9 2.1-2.55 1.949-4.2-.149-1.649-1.199-3-2.85-3.6-1.95-.75-3.15-2.55-3.15-4.65-.151-1.951.899-3.6 2.698-4.501z"/></symbol>
</svg>

<div class="text-with-borders">
  <svg class="thumbs" role="img"><use xlink:href="#thumbs"/></svg>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
</div>
```